# get spesific information from sql database with python script

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a script that needs to get specific details from a database that contains a problem tickets information, when I'm querying the database I'm getting this kind of information:

> [{'Id': b'384905', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'54094', 'CustomFieldId': b'6', 'TextValue': b'data'}, {'Id': b'384906', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'someurl', 'CustomFieldId': b'3', 'TextValue': b'someurl'}, {'Id': b'384907', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'74', 'CustomFieldId': b'23', 'TextValue': b'data'}, {'Id': b'384908', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'Dallas', 'CustomFieldId': b'24', 'TextValue': b'Dallas'}, {'Id': b'384909', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'4', 'CustomFieldId': b'7', 'TextValue': 
>   b'United States'}]

what I want to do for example is to get the value that is assigned for  'CustomFieldId': b'7'in the list, for example, its 'Value': b'4' as we see in the last list, and then I want to to turn that value into integer and keep that dynamic, for example, if 'CustomFieldId' is 7 (called it location) then bring me the value
what I tried so far:

```
from MySQLdb import _mysql
import MySqlQuery
Eventid = 5
sport = 6
location = 7
league = 8
league_name = 24
db = _mysql.connect(host="somedb",user="someuser",passwd="somepass")
db.query("SELECT * FROM `NOC`.`TicketFields` WHERE `TicketId` = '133328' LIMIT 0,1000")
r=db.store_result()
result = r.fetch_row(maxrows=0,how=1)
ticket = []
for x in result:
ticket.append(x)
for item in ticket:
print(int(item["CustomFieldId"]))
```

Thanks
Update, @ZarakiKenpachi comment helped me but now i need to get a string, what i did was something like this:

```
for s in ticket:
id = int(s.get('CustomFieldId'))
if id == league_name:
    leaguename = str(s.get('Value'))
    print(leaguename)
```

im getting this output:
b'Dallas'
how can i get only Dallas without the b or ' '?

Comment: Please avoid external links, include the code (properly formatted) in the question.

Comment: @Jacob you need to get `Value` by specifying `CustomFieldId` number?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [{'Id': b'384905', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'54094', 'CustomFieldId': b'6', 'TextValue': b'data'}, {'Id': b'384906', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'someurl', 'CustomFieldId': b'3', 'TextValue': b'someurl'}, {'Id': b'384907', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'74', 'CustomFieldId': b'23', 'TextValue': b'data'}, {'Id': b'384908', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'Dallas', 'CustomFieldId': b'24', 'TextValue': b'Dallas'}, {'Id': b'384909', 'TicketId': b'133328', 'Field': None, 'Value': b'4', 'CustomFieldId': b'7', 'TextValue': b'United States'}]

customer_field = 7
for item in data:
    id = int(item.get('CustomFieldId'))
    if id == customer_field:
        value = int(item.get('Value'))
        print(value)
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks Works Perfect!, But i need to do few more things if you can help me.
1. im getting a output twice for example:
4
4
how can i get the output only once?
2.im trying to do the same thing but now i want to get the value of customfield6
i added this lines:
for s in result:
    id == int(s.get('CustomFieldId'))
    if id == sport:
        sportid = int(s.get('Value'))
        print (sportid)
but im getting nothing

Comment: @Jacob how you get output twice? Don't see any sportId in you data.